# Triangle Minimum Area Problem

Tags: geometry

Consider a triangle of vertices $A = (0,0), B = (2,4)$ and the vertex $C=(x,y)$ on the parabola defined by the function
$$f(x) = x^2 - 2kx + k^2+ 2k + 6.$$
where $k$ is a fixed real number. How high is the minimum area triangle with respect to the base $\overline{AB}$?

Can you help me with this problem? At first I thought it was silly, but I've already lost almost a day trying to do it and nothing... :(

Comment: Do you know rhe formula for the area of a triangle in terms of the co-ordinates of its vertices?

Comment: Is C the vertex of the parabola?

Comment: I tried to use Heron's relationship, derive and find the critical points. Only I couldn't get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

First let's calculate the base and height of triangle $ABC$
\begin{align*}
b&=d(A,B)=\sqrt{4^2+2^2}=2\sqrt{5}\\
h&=d(C,\mathcal L)\\
h&=\displaystyle\frac{|(x^2-2kx+k^2+2k+6)-2x|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}}\\
h&=\frac{|x^2-2(k+1)x+(k+1)^2+5|}{\sqrt{5}}\\
h&=\frac{|(x-(k+1))^2+5|}{\sqrt{5}}\\
h&=\frac{(x-(k+1))^2+5}{\sqrt{5}}\\
\text{Área}&=\frac{bh}{2}\\
\text{Área}&=(x-(k+1))^2+5\geq 5
\end{align*}
Where the area reaches its minimum when $x=k+1$, then $h=\dfrac{5}{\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, man. I tried to use similar things, but faltered when trying to assemble the solution structure.